# SFDX force:org:clone not working

Tags: salesforcedx, sandbox, force-org-clone

I am playing around with the force:org:clone command(which is in BETA) but can't get it to work.

Here's the command I put together: `sfdx force:org:clone -u me@mysandbox.com.full -a FULL_CLONE -t sandbox`

The error I get is: `To indicate which sandbox org you want to clone, specify SourceSandboxName in a definition file or as a command line argument.`

I looked at all the arguments that are listed for the command and don't see anything related to `SourceSandboxName`. Isn't the `username` making it clear enough which sandbox I am trying to clone?

In addition it appears that the documentation is incorrect, if you take a look at their example its referencing `sfdx force:org:create`.

Here's a link to the documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_org.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We got an answer on [social media](https://twitter.com/rohitforce/status/1138909708578779137):

> The docs for the sandbox operations and the help topic fixes are scheduled to be published today. -u needs to point to the org with sandbox licenses ie the prod org. SourceSandboxName is a field in the definition file, not the command and should reference sandbox being cloned.

The appropriate command will look like this:

```
sfdx force:org:clone -f config/cloned-sandbox.json -u prod-org -t sandbox
```

The docs should reflect this soon.

Comment: Thanks for following up on this.

Comment: What values we should have in the cloned-sandbox.json file, like key=value pair @sfdcfox

Comment: @YaswanthTikkisetti It's a JSON file, so something like `{ "SourceSandboxName": "sbname" }` You can also just use `SourceSandboxName=sbname` on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Hello below is a command used to clone a developer org. I will explain each parameter.

```
sfdx force:org:clone -t sandbox SandboxName=DevSbx1 SourceSandboxName=jnbanksan -u prod -a MyDevSandbox
```

1. -t specifies its a sandbox to be created
2. SandboxName - is the actual JSON field name in the definition field schema, which denotes your sandbox name.
3. -u is the authenticated prod instance,
4. -a is the alias to reference this newly created sandbox
5. SourceSandboxName is the actual existing org name you wish to clone not the org alias.